# Change product tabs expand/collapse icons

Tags: tabs, magento2.3.3, mobile

I want to change the expand / collapse icons of the product tab from @icon-up / @icon-down to @icon-expand / @icon-collapse (mobile view). I changed the mage-init and added the icons options like written in the docs. The new icons just got added as a span, but they did not replace the up/down icons. After that I looked for the classed in my _extend.less and _theme.less (luma) but the only thing I found was a class named .abs-toggling-title which is not used by the tabs. I don't understand why the tabs are not overwritten.

```
 <div class="product data items the-grid-pda-col-1"
         data-mage-init='
         {
            "tabs":{
                "openedState":"active",
                "active":"false",
                "icons": {
                    "header": "ico-expand",
                    "activeHeader": "ico-collapse"
                    }
            }
         }
        '
    >
```

The ico-expand and ico-collapse in mage-init are classes which are adding a svg via the icon lib.

Answer (score 0):

actually it was pretty easy. The css is located in css/source/_sections.less.

I just had to change the corresponding icon libs in common and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

you can edit your less like this:

```
.product{
&.detailed{
    .items{
        .title{
            &:after{
                content:'down-arrow';
            }
            &.active{
                &:after{
                    content:'up-arrow';
                }
            }
        }
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: Select code and use Ctrl+k for code format @Mark Henry